# .Net - tool to send html emails

Tags: html, email

I am looking for a tool to send html emails from WCF Service.
Currently using Chilkat to do same but in some version of outlook it is showing html emails as multiple attachments (of html file and Images).

Can anyone guide for solution to above or any better tool to send html emails.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using aspNetEmail component to send HTML emails,
issue of multiple attachemnts in outlook is resolved.
Thanks to aspNetEmail commendable support!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) along with [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx)?